# Как сгенерировать таблицу по массиву?

Tags: php, html, css

У нас должна быть табличка 3 на 3.

```
array(
    'text' => 'Текст красного цвета',
    'cells' => '1,2,4,5'
),
array(
    'text' => 'Текст зеленого цвета',
    'cells' => '8,9'
),
```

Есть функция которая принимает значения типа. Цифры в массиве обозначают те ячейки, которые должны быть цельными. Нужно по этим параметрам сгенерировать таблицу. 
Как лучше всего сделать так, чтобы на выходе был страница выглядела вот так?

[image]

Comment: @noskovgleb, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я думал это сделать через тег <table> и <td> <tr>, но не знаю как учесть то, что при colspan и rowspan, некоторые части таблицы будут вылазить, а не просто объединяться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам сначала следует разобраться, как работают colspan и rowspan, если, конечно, не знаете, как они работают. Потом сделать пре-расчет для всей таблицы. Собственно заниматься этим под вечер никто умный не будет, так что советую вам завтра самому утром, на свежую голову, встать, покушать, нарисовать более приятный рисунок и начать думать, при каких условиях и каким блокам нужно добавлять colspan и rowspan, попутно помечая ручкой или карандашом пометки на белом а4 листе (это обязательно! проверено).

Т.к. сетка 3х3, то тут есть разные способы создания таблицы. Самый простой - это сделать перебор всех позиций и куда-нибудь его занести. А дальше просто смотреть значения. Но это муторно.

Дерзайте! Но если вдруг на каком-то моменте заклинит мозг, то пишите, поможем :-) Но только поможем, а не напишем.

Comment: Вот я так тоже думал сделать, сделать перебор всех позиций но это мне кажется совсем неправильно будет. Может есть какой-то другой способ, может с помощью javascript...?

Comment: @Кококо тут не суть, на каком языке писать. Важен сам алгоритм. Вот.